# send referrer header with chrome.downloads api

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create an extension which emulates the Ctrl+Click to save image feature from Opera 12. I am using chrome.downloads.download() from my extension's background script to initiate downloads, while a content script listens for the user action and sends a message with the URL of the image to download.

Everything works fine, except that on some sites such as pixiv.net, the download is interrupted and fails. Using the webRequest API, I verified that the cookie from the active tab is being sent with the download request, but no referer header is sent. I expect that this is because the site is blocking download requests from external sites. I have not been able to verify this though, as the webRequest.onError event isn't firing on a failed download.

I cannot set the referer header myself, as it cannot be set through chrome.downloads, and webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders cannot be used in its blocking form with a download request, so I can't add the headers later. Is there a way to start a download in the context of a tab so that it behaves like right-click > save as...?

For clarification as to how I'm starting the downloads, here is my TypeScript code stripped down to the applicable parts.

Injected script:

```
window.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (suspended) {
        return;
    }

    if (e.ctrlKey && (<Element>e.target).nodeName === 'IMG') {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            url: (<HTMLImageElement>e.target).src,
            saveAs: true,
        });

        // Prevent the click from triggering links, etc.
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        // This can trigger for multiple elements, so disable it 
        // for a moment so we don't download multiple times at once
        suspended = true;
        window.setTimeout(() => suspended = false, 100);
    }
}, true);
```

Background script:

```
interface DownloadMessage {
    url: string;
    saveAs: boolean;
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message: DownloadMessage, sender, sendResponse) => {
    chrome.downloads.download({
        url: message.url,
        saveAs: message.saveAs,
    });
});
```

**Update**

Going off of ExpertSystem's solution below, I've found a method that mostly works. When the background script receives a request to download an image, I now compare the URL's host name against a user-configured list of sites that need the workaround. If the workaround is needed, I send a message back to the tab. The tab downloads the image using an XMLHttpRequest with `responseType = 'blob'`. I then use `URL.createObjectURL()` on the blob and pass that URL back to the background script to download. This avoids any size limitations of data URIs. Also, if the XHR request fails, I force an attempt using the standard method so that the user will at least see a failed download appear.

The code now looks something like this:

Injected Script:

```
// ...Original code here...

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    switch (message.action) {
        case 'xhr-download':
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.responseType = 'blob';

            xhr.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
                    url: URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response),
                    filename: message.url.substr(message.url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
                    saveAs: message.saveAs,
                });
            });

            xhr.addEventListener('error', (e) => {
                // The XHR method failed. Force an attempt using the
                // downloads API.
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
                    url: message.url,
                    saveAs: message.saveAs,
                    forceDownload: true,
                });
            });

            xhr.open('get', message.url, true);
            xhr.send();
            break;
    }
});
```

Background Script:

```
interface DownloadMessage {
    url: string;
    saveAs: boolean;
    filename?: string;
    forceDownload?: boolean;
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message: DownloadMessage, sender, sendResponse) => {
    var downloadOptions = {
        url: message.url,
        saveAs: message.saveAs,
    };

    if (message.filename) {
        options.filename = message.filename;
    }

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = message.url;

    if (message.forceDownload || a.protocol === 'blob:' || !needsReferralWorkaround(a.hostname)) {
        // No workaround needed or the XHR workaround is giving
        // us its results.
        chrome.downloads.download(downloadOptions);

        if (a.protocol === 'blob:') {
            // We don't need the blob URL any more. Release it.
            URL.revokeObjectUrl(message.url);
        }
    } else {
        // The XHR workaround is needed. Inform the tab.
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(sender.tab.id, { 
            action: 'xhr-download', 
            url: message.url, 
            saveAs: message.saveAs
        });
    }
});
```

This will, of course, fail if the image is not on the same domain as the page and the server doesn't send CORS headers, but I figure there won't be too many sites which restrict image downloads by referrer *and* serve images from a different domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **[`chrome.download.download()`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads.html#method-download)** method's first argument (`options`) can include the **headers** property, an array of objects:

> Extra HTTP headers to send with the request if the URL uses the HTTP[s] protocol. Each header is represented as a dictionary containing the keys name and either value or binaryValue, restricted to those allowed by XMLHttpRequest.

**UPDATE:**

Unfortunately, as you pointed out the *"restricted to those allowed by XMLHttpRequest"* part makes all the different, as the `Referer` is not an allowed header for XHR either.

I messed around quite a bit with the issue, but didn't get to a satisfying solution or work-around. I did come close though, so I will present the results here in case someone finds them useful. (Besides, some of the upcoming enhancements of the HTML5 specs might actually make this a viable work-around.)

---

First of all, the easy and quick alternative (with one major? drawback though) is programmatically creating and "clicking" a link (`<a>` element) that points to the image's source URL.

**Pros:**

- Really easy and quick to implement.
- Avoids all header- and CORS-related issues (more on that later), as it happens right from within the web-page's context.
- Does not require the `chrome.downloads` API at all.
- Does not require a background-page.

**Cons:**

- There is no control over where the file is downloaded (you can specify the file-name though) and whether a file-dialog is displayed or not.

If you don't care about the images' being saved at the default "downloads" folder, then this approach could be the one :)

**Implementation:**

```
var suspended = false;
window.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if (suspended) {
        return;
    }

    if (evt.ctrlKey && (evt.target.nodeName === 'IMG')) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = evt.target.src;
        a.target = '_blank';
        a.download = a.href.substring(a.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        a.click();

        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopImmediatePropagation();

        suspended = true;
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            suspended = false;
        }, 100);
    }
}, true);
```

---

Trying to circumvent the above solution's limitation, I tried the following process:

1. When the image is Ctrl+clicked the source URL is sent to the background-page.
2. The background-page opens the URL in a new tab (so the tab's origin is the same as the images - this will be important later on).
3. The background-page injects some code into the newly created tab that:
   a. Creates a `<canvas>` element and draws the image onto it.
   b. Converts the drawn image to a dataURL.(*)
   c. Sends the dataURL back to the background-page for further processing.
4. The background-page receives the dataURL, closes the previously opened tab and initiates a download, using `chrome.downloads.download()` and the received dataURL as the value of the `url` property.

(*): To prevent *"Information leakage"* the canvas element does not allow the conversion of an image to dataURL, unless it has the same origin as the current web-pages location. That is why it was necessary to open the image's source URL in a new tab.

**Pros:**

- It allows control over whether the file-dialog will be displayed.
- It provides all the conveniences offered by the `chrome.downloads` API (if they are needed or not is different matter).
- It almost works as expected :/

**Cons - Caveats:**

- It is quite slow, since the image has to be loaded in the new tab.
- The maximum size of the images that can be saved depend on the maximum allowed length of a URL. Although I couldn't find any "official" resource about this, based on what most sources seem to indicate, images of a few hundred MB might be within limits (this is a personal estimation and could be pretty inaccurate). Nevertheless, this is a limitation.
- The major limitation comes form the fact that canvas' `toDataURL()` *returns the data at a resolution of 96dpi*. So, especially for high-resolution images, this is a show-stopper.
  The good news: It's sibling method `toDataURLHD()` *returns it (the data) at the native canvas bitmap resolution*.
  The not-so-good news: `toDataURLHD()` is not currently supported by Google Chrome.

You can find more info on the specifications of `canvas` and its `toDataURL()` / `toDataURLHD()` methods **[here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurlhd)**. Hopefully, it will be supported soon, which will bring this solution back into the game :)

**Implementation:**

A sample extension would consist of 3 files:

1. `manifest.json`: The manifest
2. `content.js`:    The content-script
3. `background.js`: The background-page

*manifest.json:*

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",
    "offline_enabled": false,

    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches":    ["*://*/*"],
        "js":         ["content.js"],
        "run_at":     "document_idle",
        "all_frames": true
    }],

    "permissions": [
        "downloads",
        "*://*/*"
    ],
}
```

*content.js:*

```
var suspended = false;
window.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if (suspended) {
        return;
    }

    if (evt.ctrlKey && (evt.target.nodeName === 'IMG')) {

        /* Initialize the "download" process
         * for the specified image's source-URL */
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            action: 'downloadImgStart',
            url:    evt.target.src
        });

        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopImmediatePropagation();

        suspended = true;
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            suspended = false;
        }, 100);
    }
}, true);
```

*background.js:*

```
/* This function, which will be injected into the tab with the image,
 * takes care of putting the image into a canvas and converting it to a dataURL
 * (which is sent back to the background-page for further processing) */
var imgToDataURL = function() {
    /* Determine the image's name, type, desired quality etc */
    var src     = window.location.href;
    var name    = src.substring(src.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    var type    = /\.jpe?g([?#]|$)/i.test(name) ? 'image/jpeg' : 'image/png';
    var quality = 1.0;

    /* Load the image into a canvas and convert it to a dataURL */
    var img = document.body.querySelector('img');
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(type, quality);

    /* If the specified type was not supported (falling back to the default
     * 'image/png'), update the `name` accordingly */
    if ((type !== 'image/png') && (dataURL.indexOf('data:image/png') === 0)) {
        name += '.png';
    }

    /* Pass the dataURL and `name` back to the background-page */
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        action: 'downloadImgEnd',
        url:    dataURL,
        name:   name
    });
}

/* An 'Immediatelly-invoked function expression' (IIFE)
 * to be injected into the web-page containing the image */
var codeStr = '(' + imgToDataURL + ')();';

/* Listen for messages from the content scripts */
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender) {

    /* Require that the message contains a 'URL' */
    if (!msg.url) {
        console.log('Invalid message format: ', msg);
        return;
    }

    switch (msg.action) {
    case 'downloadImgStart':
        /* Request received from the original page:
         * Open the image's source-URL in an unfocused, new tab
         * (to avoid "tainted canvas" errors due to CORS)
         * and inject 'imgToDataURL' */
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: msg.url,
            active: false
        }, function(tab) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                code:      codeStr,
                runAt:     'document_idle',
                allFrames: false
            });
        });
        break;
    case 'downloadImgEnd':
        /* The "dirty" work is done: We acquired the dataURL !
         * Close the "background" tab and initiate the download */
        chrome.tabs.remove(sender.tab.id);
        chrome.downloads.download({
            url:      msg.url,
            filename: msg.name || '',
            saveAs:   true
        });
        break;
    default:
        /* Repot invalie message 'action' */
        console.log('Invalid action: ', msg.action, ' (', msg, ')');
        break;
    }
});
```

---

<sub>Sorry for the long answer (which does not exactly propose a working solution either).

I hope someone finds something useful in there (or at least saves some time trying out the same things).</sub>

Comment: The key part of that being "restricted to those allowed by XMLHttpRequest." Referer can't be set.

Comment: Seems, like I missed that. Could you post some code (or a specific image URL that is interrupted, because I seem to be able to download them without any problem).

Comment: Any of the high-resolution images on pixiv will fail to download—http://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=big&illust_id=40236819 for example. If I right-click > Save As on the image, it downloads properly, but `chrome.downloads.download({ url: 'http://i1.pixiv.net/img121/img/tsuguminoto/40236819.jpg', saveAs: true })` fails.

Using the webRequest API, I could see that the browser (Opera 20 in this case) was sending a cookie header which matched `document.cookie` from the page whose content script sent the message to the background script, so I don't think authentication is the problem.

Comment: @Joel: I updated the answer with two partial work-arounds (not a 100% working solution). I spent quite some time trying to figure this out, but I couldn't. I just thought I'd share my "experience" is case someone finds something useful in there.

Comment: @Joel: Not even a tiny little comment on my lengthy effort ? :( :D

Comment: Sorry. I've been on break the past week, and I haven't been at my computer very much. I'll take a look at it once I get back in a couple of days.

Comment: I had tried something similar to creating and clicking a link to the image before the downloads API existed, but couldn't get it working. I'm adding an option to save images directly to the downloads folder, so that solution works perfectly there. I don't like the canvas to Data URL solution, as that wouldn't work (or would be massively more complicated) when dealing with animated images, but that gives me another idea. If something like chrome.webRequest allows me to send a referer header, I could download the image, convert the raw data to a URL and pass that to chrome.downloads.

Comment: I found I can just use XHR from the tab to get the image as a blob, then pass a URL reference to the blob back to the background script. This any size limits on data URLs, and it works for all image types. I've updated my original post with the relevant code.

Comment: Nice one ! I totally missed the `responseType` property :)